# Random number by percentages C++

Tags: loops, if-statement, random

So the problem is to random balls range from 0-100 ( 100%) while 30% can be red 20% can be blue and 50% can be green , I did sth like this:
If  chance smaller than 20 then cout red
If chance smaller than 50 then cout blue
If chance smaller or equal 100 then cout green
Any suggestions to fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

if you have random number in range [1-100] then logic will be

```
if (num <= 30) return "red"; // covers [1-30]
if (num <= 30+20) return "blue"; // covers [31-50]
return "green"; // covers [51-100]
```

Comment: more like 30<num<=50 to cover [31-50]

Comment: @TrươngQuốcAnhDuy no, first if returns so, we don't need two comparisons in 2nd case

Answer (score 0):

The best representation for percentages are floating points, 0% is 0 and 100% is

Thankfully C# provides a great opinionated function for this purpose: Random.NextDouble()

To generate a random float just call it like so:

> Random seeded_random_number_generator = new Random();
>   red_portion = seeded_random_number_generator.NextDouble();

Finally to use your double just multiply it by the other factor.

> area_to_paint_red = red_portion * shape_area

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.nextdouble?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: 1.

The reason is both mathematical and architectural: One quarter of all possible float numbers can be found within 0 and 1. Do not use a range of 0 to 100, the representations possible between 0 and 1 are much more densely packed than from 1 to 100, there are more numbers between 0 and 1 than between 1 to 100 (in float architectures). Besides, a 0 to 1 representation is more mathematically sane, since 1 is the multiplicative identity in the same manner that 100% is.

Comment: Whoops, just realized that the question is asking for C++ not C#. The random function I could find in C++ is really ugly, it includes a division and I want no part in it.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution

If someone wants to change this answer so that it fits the C++ language, feel welcome to do so.

Comment: So the problem is generate random numbers and the probability of you getting red is 30% , 20% for blue and 50% for green its just basically if statement but I can’t figure out the math for the condition